# How to implement pb message polymorphism like c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, protocol-buffers

In C++, I have a class T, it's constructed like:

```
class T {
public:
    T(X* x) { // X is pb message 
     .....
    }
    // some func use x
    .....
};
```

Then, a class A which uses T like:

```
class A {
    void funcA(X* x) { // X is pb message 
        T* t = new T(x);
        ....
    }
};
```

And now, a new class B wants to use T, but this class use message Y. Message Y and X are similar. But it was already used by other service, so I can't just change it to X. (So does X.)

```
class B {
    void funcB(Y* y) { // y is pb message, which is similar with x. 
        T* t = new T(y); // error
        ....
    }
};
```

Copy T and make a new class T1 can solve this problem, but it's weird, not a good design.

```
class T1 {
public:
    T1(Y* y) { // y is pb message 
     .....
    }
    // some func use y
    .....
};
```

If X, Ys were common C++ class, I could make them inherit from Z, and change `T(X* x);` to `T(Z* z);`  But they are both pb message, is there any solution? Maybe change T constructor to a template func?

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps a sample code of showcasing what you want to achieve might help one to visualize your question better.

Comment: Could `template <class Msg> class T { T(Msg* msg) {...} };` work?

Comment: if you ask me, I think you need to have 2 different classes. Because if `X` and `Y` are not same message, handling those message will be different. if they have same fields, then you need to handle them on same class. I think it is somehow really rare that you have 2 different messages that are **exactly** similar and if you do, I think I will merge them as a single message and use another field to show its type or use reflection to get its name.

Comment: Template is an appropriate solution. It will work! @m88